# Very weird IIS6 asp.net website behaviour

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-3.5

I have a weird issue with my website. This is asp.net(.net 3.5) website hosted on a dedicated server IIS6.

Recently I got a strange behavior, the website hangs and just doesn’t reply unless I go to iis and restart either app pool or whole IIS - BUT what is the most strange thing is that in case I go to remote desktop of the server and try to access it locally it DOES work just fine.

I read couple threads about deadlocking and hanging because of memory leaks and non closed sql connections BUT why it still does work from the local?

In case there is something wrong with the code – why does it still work from locally?

In case there is some issues on the hosting side (like firewall issues)  then why does iisreset help?

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Probably network issues. Try to see with Fiddler where's the time being *wasted*.

Comment: SHould this be on ServerFault.com?

Answer (score 1):

We've just run into this problem, and we have a solution.  IIS has two thread pools to handle requests.  One thread pool is used for external requests.  Another pool is used for local requests.  Our problem was caused by a deadlock in backend code.  Once the deadlock occurred, all external requests were queued but not serviced because all of the servicing threads were in use.  Opening the website from the web server uses the other thread pool, so the requests are serviced.  We were absolutley positive it was a network issue, but WinDbg proved otherwise.
See here for more information:
[MSDN blog entry about IIS and threads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)

[minLocalRequestFreeThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.minlocalrequestfreethreads.aspx)

(Also, search for minFreeThreads to see the non-local request thread pools.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the website hangs for all external users, so that it's not just one single user?

The IIS only runs one page at a time for each user, so if one request is caught in an eternal loop, that single user will experience that the server has stopped completely as no pages at all work until that page times out. The server will still work as usual for other users.

You can test this by using a different browser, or starting a new instance of the same browser (possible with IE, not with Firefox).

Comment: Yes I tried from like 5 different machines and the only place the website works is from local. I also tried different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not enough info to really give you an answer, but I would look at your firewall first if it responds locally from the server. Do you have another server behind the FW like a SQL server? Try browsing from that as it will show you where the problem is.

My though would be a badly configured load balancer.

Comment: SQL server is on the same machine. I don't have any load balancers so all requests go to this same machine. I double checked the domain is being resolved to same ip from local and externally.

Also there are other websites on this same machine and they are accessible externally even in case my website is down.

Comment: OK this sounds like a job for wireshark then, get it installed somewhere between your FW and the webserver and also external to the firewall, capture traffic from both sides when it stops serving the page. i.e. when its non responsive if you see traffic coming from the webserver but stopping at the FW, then you know where the problem is. If nothing leaves the webserver start looking at code. Have you tried cloning the website and creating a dev copy of it? Would be worth it to see if it is code or site specific (IIS can get weird with the metabase, a clone could reveal issues) Good luck!